# "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" - it IS defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I have the following index.pug file on my server that I am trying to render:

```
block content
    h1.
        User List
          ul
            each user, i in userlist
              li
                a(href="mailto:#{user.username}")= user.username
```

And my node.js app's code:

```
app.get('/sign-up', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db
var collection = db.get('_User')
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
res.render('index', {"userlist":docs})})
})
```

I get the following error upon trying to open 'sign-up':
"Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

Why might I be getting this error? I do have the collection called '_User' and it has 'username' key in it.

Comment: You are not checking for errors in the find callback.

Comment: What does that have to do with the property being 'undefined'?

Comment: If you don't check for errors in the callback and there is an error, the value of docs is undefined, resulting in the error you are seeing in pug file.

Comment: How would I handle that error, for example?

Comment: Like this? collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
if (e) throw (e)
res.render('index', {"userlist":docs})
})

Comment: nvm I got it. thanks for the help